# ReactJs - TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'transform' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was planning to change the inline css by hovering the element.
But react freaked out cuz all the properties of the 'style' object in this class are somehow all readonly.

But it is fine to modify it in 'render' method.
I searched the error message, many people get this error message by modifying the props object.But this one is not even in the props object.
Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Game extends Component {
   state = {

   }

   style = {
      height: '200px',
      backgroundImage: 'url()',
      backgroundSize: 'cover',
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      backgroundPosition: 'center',
      transform: 'scale(1)'
   }

   onHover() {
      this.style.transform = 'scale(1.2)';
   }

   render() {
      const { game, onClick } = this.props;
      const { img, name } = game;
      this.style.backgroundImage = `url(${img})`;
      this.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
      return (
         <div className="m-2"
            style={this.style}
            onClick={() => { onClick(this.props.game) }}
            onMouseEnter={() => this.onHover()}
         >{name}</div>
      );
   }
}
```

Can't attach images yet, so here's the link for the error message.

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THBm4.png)

Comment: Is it possible that "style" is a reserved property of components, and hence is treated as read only? Sorry, I've not seen this readonly issue before, so am curious if renaming "style" to something else would work.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the first thing I've tried, but didn't work. I figured it out by Bhojendra Rauniyar's answer below. Thanks <3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to update the property in react is to **update the state with setState**. Alternatively, you should place them inside the render hook itself or where you require them:

```
render() {
  const { game, onClick } = this.props;
  const { img, name } = game;
  const style = {
      height: '200px',
      backgroundImage: 'url()',
      backgroundSize: 'cover',
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      backgroundPosition: 'center',
      transform: 'scale(1)'
   }
  // now, you can modify
  style.backgroundImage = `url(${img})`;
  style.transform = 'scale(1)';
```

Or, even you may place them outside the class: (This would be preferred method in your case because, you're updating the properties in desired methods)

```
const style = {
   height: '200px',
   backgroundImage: 'url()',
   backgroundSize: 'cover',
   backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
   backgroundPosition: 'center',
   transform: 'scale(1)'
}
export default class Game extends Component {
  render() {
    // modifying style
    style.backgroundImage = `url(${img})`;
    style.transform = 'scale(1)';
```

Comment: That's it! I put the style object inside of the render method, then modify the transform by a flag value inside of the state object which is modified by onHover method. Everyting works as it should be now. Thanks!

Comment: didn't work if the object is nested for example let styles=  {
      root:{
         color:'white'
      }
}

received same error

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your style object and change the copy:

```
render() {
  const { game, onClick } = this.props;
  const { img, name } = game;

  // make a copy
  let changedStyle = {
    ...this.style
  }

  // change the copy
  changedStyle.backgroundImage = `url(${img})`;
  changedStyle.transform = 'scale(1)';

  return (
     <div className="m-2"
        style={changedStyle}
        onClick={() => { onClick(this.props.game) }}
        onMouseEnter={() => this.onHover()}
     >{name}</div>
  );
}
```

---

To make it even cleaner, you could just merge css classes via

```
style = {
    height: '200px',
    backgroundImage: 'url()',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    transform: 'scale(1)',
}

hoveringStyle = {
    transform: 'scale(1.2)',
}

this.style  = {...style, ...hoveringStyle}
```

This may have a negative side effect that i don't know about.