# Type Error: Cannot assign to read only property 'backgroundColor' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-props, react-state

I'm using React to create a component that will render a different background depending on its property. However, I don't know how to change its property without collapsing the React frame.
Here's my code:

```
const inactiveStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "",
  color: "white",
};

const activeStyle = {
  color: "black"
};


export default class DrumPad extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      style: inactiveStyle,
    };
  render(){
     inactiveStyle.backgroundColor = this.props.backgroundColor
     return (<div style={this.state.style}></div>)
```

When I tried it, this is the error I get:

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'backgroundColor' of object '#'

I have tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143027/reactjs-typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-transform-of-object) but it doesn't work, because my original code is already a constant, not a state itself. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line `inactiveStyle.backgroundColor = this.props.style` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Comment: @Siddharth in my props, there is a specific value of background color that I want to add to my inactiveStyle only (and not my activeStyle). Thus I still want the state style to be there

Comment: Objects are references, so you're actually mutating the current state object. [Do not mutate the state.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980)

Comment: @EmileBergeron unfortunately no, I understand I shouldn't be mutating the state directly, but I have no idea how to change the backgroundColor using set state

Comment: Syntax wise, I don't see any issue in the code you've posted. Are you sure, error is coming on this line `inactiveStyle.backgroundColor = this.props.backgroundColor`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel like you need state at all here since it's based on the props value or a default.

```
const DrumPad = ({ backgroundColor, ...props }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      backgroundColor,
      color: 'white',
    }}
  >
    ...
  </div>
);
```

You've not shared all the relevant code, but if you want to toggle on some `isActive` prop, you can still do it like this:

```
const inactiveStyle = { color: 'white' };
const activeStyle = { color: 'black' };

const DrumPad = ({ isActive, backgroundColor, ...props }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      ...(isActive ? activeStyle : inactiveStyle),
      backgroundColor
    }}
  >
    ...
  </div>
);
```

If, for some reason, you'd still like to use the component's state, make a copy of the default style object and [use the props to initialize the state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47341539/1218980), then use `this.setState` to update it.

Note that there's no benefit at all to the following code and I've just put it together as an example of how the `setState` API works.

```
const inactiveStyle = { color: 'white' };
const activeStyle = { color: 'black' };

class DrumPad extends Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false,
    style: {
      ...inactiveStyle,
      backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor
    }
  }

  onClick = () => {
    // toggle the active state and style.
    this.setState(({ style, isActive }) => ({
      isActive: !isActive,
      style: {
        ...style,
        ...(!isActive ? activeStyle : inactiveStyle),
      },
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div style={this.state.style} onClick={this.onClick}>
          ...
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

If you'd like the state to be updated based on both props and the previous state when any of them changes, there's now [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).